React Native TextInput Ref Callback is not working as expected. It was called every time typing
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {}
    }
    _change = (e) => {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }
    refCallback = (el) => {
        console.log("change")
    }

    _style = { backgroundColor: 'red', marginTop: 30 }

    render() {
        return <TextInput
            style={this._style}
            ref={this.refCallback}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this._change}
        />
    }
}

refCallBack is called everytime I typing in the TextInput
I have tried with web and got not problems.
"When the  DOM node is added to the screen, React will call your ref callback with the DOM node as the argument. When that  DOM node is removed, React will call your ref callback with null."
I should be call twice when DOM mounted and removed
I tried with input (web) -> it's worked
I tried with TextInput ( react native) -> it should be called twice when input mounted and removed

maybe you should define function for ref callback inside constructor like here https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

still the same result
